# Service unit test expect(service).toBeTruthy() fails

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to write unit tests for a service. The very first test fails,
with this error:

> NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[HttpClient]:
>
> > StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpClient]:
> >
> > > NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!

I don't understand this because no where do I use `HttpClient` in the service being tested.

spec file:

```js
export class MockApiService {

  private apiUrl = 'apiUrl';

  get(endPoint: string) {
     return new Observable<{data: 'data'}>();
   }

   post(endPoint: string, data: any) {
     return new Observable<{data: 'data'}>();
   }

   patch(endPoint: string, data: any) {
     return new Observable<{data: 'data'}>();
   }

   getApiUrl() {
     return this.apiUrl;
   }
}

describe('TimeSlotService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      TimeSlotService,
      { provide: ApiService, useValue: MockApiService }
    ]
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: TimeSlotService = TestBed.get(TimeSlotService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

time slot service file:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TimeSlotService {

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }

  static toPeriods(timeSlots: TimeSlot[]): string[] {
    const periods: string[] = [];
    for (const timeSlot of timeSlots) {
      periods.push(timeSlot.start + ' - ' + timeSlot.end);
    }
    return periods;
  }

  getTimeSlots() {
    return this.api.get('timeSlots')
      .pipe(map(ApiService.extractData));
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Not too sure about the error but you definitely need to add the service you are trying to test to your TestBed providers list as well.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig I actually tried that as well but it gave the same error. But I will change it since it still wouldn't work if this error goes away

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig Very stupid of me but your suggestion actually did fix it... I tried your suggestion on a component unit test before but it failed there, hence my confusion.

Comment: Please don't ask a question and once that's working change the question to a new one. Please open a new question otherwise those answers we gave don't make any sense to anybody reading your question.

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig Understood, I'll change it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is misleading, you are missing the service under test inside your TestBed providers list.

Comment: I'll have a look as soon as it's a new question. Maybe comment the link. Then it'll be easier to find.

Comment: Will take about 90 minutes because of a post limit. I'll post link here by that time.

Comment: Oh ok. No worries. I'll have a look then.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57163686/expectcomponent-tobetruthy-fails] new question

Answer (score 0):

Angular is telling you that it can't inject `HttpClient` so you can easily fix with importing `HttpClientTestingModule`

```
describe('TimeSlotService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: ApiService, useValue: MockApiService }
    ],
    imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ]
  }));

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: TimeSlotService = TestBed.get(TimeSlotService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

This fix doesn't solve your misunderstanding usage of HttpClient. Maybe you should not use `useValue` but `useClass`