# expect(component).toBeTruthy() fails

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I want to write unit tests for a component. The very first test fails,
with this error:

> Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.

`it` block outputting the error:

```js
it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

login template:

```html
<h3>Login</h3>
<form class="form form-group" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="email" class="login-form-label col-4">Email:</label>
    <input ngModel [(ngModel)]="email" name="email" (ngModelChange)="validateEmail()" type="email" id="email" class="col-3 form-control">
    <span class="error col-sm-4">{{ this.emailErr }}</span>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <label for="password" class="login-form-label col-4">Wachtwoord:</label>
    <input ngModel [(ngModel)]="password" name="password" (ngModelChange)="validatePassword()" type="password" id="password" class="col-3 form-control">
    <span class="error col-sm-4">{{ this.passwordErr }}</span>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" [disabled]="!isValid()" value="Login" class="login-button col-1">
</form>
```

I tried:

```js
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        LoginComponent,
        { provide: RoutingService, useValue: MockRoutingService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });
```

Also:

```js
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        LoginComponent,
        { provide: RoutingService, useValue: MockRoutingService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

And also:

```js
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        LoginComponent,
        { provide: RoutingService, useValue: MockRoutingService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

`LoginComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  private password = '';
  private email = '';
  private emailErr = '';
  private passwordErr = '';

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private routingService: RoutingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.emailErr = '';
    this.passwordErr = '';

    const response: { ['emailValid']: boolean, ['passwordValid']: boolean } = this.authService.login(this.email, this.password);

    const self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (response.emailValid === false) {
        self.emailErr = '* Your username was incorrect, please try again.';
        return;
      } else if (response.passwordValid === false) {
        self.passwordErr = '* Your password was incorrect, please try again.';
        return;
      }
      self.routingService.route('home');
    }, 300);
  }

  validateEmail() {
    this.emailErr = '';
    if (this.email === '') {
      this.emailErr = '* Please enter your email.';
    }
  }

  validatePassword() {
    this.passwordErr = '';
    if (this.password === '') {
      this.passwordErr = '* Please enter your password.';
    }
  }

  isValid() {
    if (this.password === '' || this.email === '') {
      return false;
    } else if (this.emailErr !== '' || this.passwordErr !== '') {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try reducing your code samples and come up with a more specific question. This is a lot of source to review

Comment: @Gnqz I reduced it, not sure if I should keep the login component in the post though.

Comment: The error is inside the first ```it``` block asserting that the component is defined? As said in the answer below you definitely need to remove the LoginComponent from the providers list and use async inside the beforeEach declaring your TestBed configuration. Could you please share the test case (```it``` block) inside the spec which fails and your LoginComponent template (the html)?

Comment: @Erbsenkoenig Just updated post, hope it's of some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nash11 pointed out, you definitely need to remove the `LoginComponent` from the providers list and the first `beforeEach` should run `async`.

I would expect that doing this you actually should get a different message, telling you that ngModel is not a known property of an `<input/>`

There are two ways of getting your test to work, depending if you want the `[{ngModel}]` to work like it usually does or if you only want to shallow test your application where you're not interested in how `[{ngModel}]` actually works.

So if you want that ngModel just works, you would need to import the `FormsModule` into your TestBed.

If you don't mind that ngModel works but is just a property which exists you could set the `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` inside your TestBed.

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [
              { provide: RoutingService, useValue: MockRoutingService },
              { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: MockAuthenticationService }],
            // imports: [FormsModule] // import the FormsModule if you want ngModel to be working inside the test
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA] // remove the FormsModule import and use that schema to only shallow test your component. Please refer to the official document for more information.
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Here is a working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-callback-jazzfc)

Answer (score 0):

`LoginComponent` is not a `provider`. It is enough to add it to the declarations. Try removing `LoginComponent` from your `providers` and run the test again.

I would go with your third option. The `async` makes it possible for all the asynchronous code to finish before continuing.

```
describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: RoutingService, useValue: MockRoutingService },
        { provide: AuthenticationService, useValue: MockAuthenticationService }
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: This resulted in the exact same error unfortunately